Rust - как получить возращаемое значение у метода?
Есть метод  read_to_end, позволяющий прочитать файл побайтово до  EOF. Он возвращает результат и размер в байтах (пример:"Ok(35096)"). А как получить от него только размер, чтобы использовать в дальнейшем для указания размера при создании другого файла?  Как мне его возвращенный результат по размеру в байтах преобразовать в u64?

Эм, банальные unwrap и каст в u64?

Мне больше не понятно как из результата получить только размер . let file_size: Result<usize, std::io::Error>  . Как значение в usize получить?

Эм, банальный unwrap? Об этом написано сразу же во второй главе растбука (и более подробно в девятой), непонятно почему у вас затруднения какие-то

(а хотя немного вру, во второй главе не unwrap, а expect, но на суть не влияет)

Все понял , спасибо. let file_size = f.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();

Чтобы узнать размер файла нет никакой нужды читать его содержимое.
